# A simple characterization of the Brownian Motion

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

A well-known characterization of the Brownian Motion says that it is the only continuous process $X_t$ (defined on $[0,\infty)$) such that

- $P(X_0=0)=1$, $E[X_t^2]=t$, $E[X_t]=0$ for any $t\ge 0$
- the increments are independent, that is $X_{t_n}-X_{t_{n-1}},\dots,X_{t_1}-X_{t_0}$ are independent for any finite sequence $0\le t_0<t_1<\dots<t_n$
- for any $h>0$ the law of $X_{t+h}-X_t$ depends only on $h$
- $E[|X_t|^3]\le C$ for any $t\in [0,\delta]$, where $C$ and $\delta$ are some positive constants (this is the only technical hypothesis).

I read that there is an elementary proof of this characterization (i.e. that such a process is a Brownian Motion) based on the central limit theorem (in fact, the only thing to show is that the increments have normal distribution, so it is reasonable that CLT could help), but I fail to see how this can be done. Do you have any ideas or references?

**Update:** Apparently, the last technical hypothesis is not necessary. See my answer below.

Comment: Proof? Isn't that the definition? You mean proof that it is unique?

Comment: No, as I said we do not know that the increments are gaussian. This is the only thing to be shown

Comment: ooooohhhh sorry. mgf maybe?

Comment: I tried to mimic the usual proof of CLT with characteristic functions, but to no avail (one would need the much stronger hypothesis $E[|X_t|^3]=o(t)$..)

Comment: I think it should work something like this: take an increment $X_t-X_s$ with $s<t$. Then, you can slash up that increment in ever smaller increments that are independent. The central limit theorem then tells you that the sum of those increments is distributed normally. But that sum is exactly $X_t-X_s$.

Comment: The problem is that you haven't enough information about the distribution of the smaller increments, so you cannot invoke the central limit theorem in such a direct way..

Comment: Where did you read this characterisation? If we manage to show that $n\mathbb P(|X_{t/n}| >\varepsilon)\to 0 $ for each $\varepsilon$ we would be done (using the moment assumption, we can apply Lindeberg's theorem).

Comment: I read it in some lecture notes in Italian.. By the way, the fact that $n\mathbb{P}(|X_{t/n}|>\epsilon)\to 0$ seems to be easy: $n\mathbb{P}(|X_{t/n}|>\epsilon)=\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb{P}(|X_{\frac{i}{n}t}-X_{\frac{i-1}{n}t}|>\epsilon)$, but by independency $\prod_i \mathbb{P}(|X_{\frac{i}{n}t}-X_{\frac{i-1}{n}t}|\le\epsilon)=\mathbb{P}(\sup_{1\le i\le n} |X_{\frac{i}{n}t}-X_{\frac{i-1}{n}t}|\le\epsilon)\to 1$, so $\prod_i(1-\mathbb{P}(|X_{\frac{i}{n}t}-X_{\frac{i-1}{n}t}|>\epsilon))\to 1$ and this implies $\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb{P}(|X_{\frac{i}{n}t}-X_{\frac{i-1}{n}t}|>\epsilon)\to 0$

Comment: I can read Italian so you can share the notes (if you are allowed of course). Why do you get the convergence to $1$?

Comment: By continuity $\mathbb{P}(\sup_{1\le i\le n} |X_{\frac{i}{n}t}-X_{\frac{i-1}{n}t}|\le\epsilon)\to 1$. The notes are here http://users.dma.unipi.it/~flandoli/dispense_Istituzioni_2014.pdf (p. 52)

Comment: You right. Grazie per il documento, fare certamente progredire il mio italiano.  "La gaussianità si dimostra nello stesso modo del teorema limite
centrale, ma facendo entrare in gioco la continuità delle traiettorie. Questa parte è
piuttosto tecnica e la omettiamo."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, we have to show that for each $t$, the random variable $X_t$ is Gaussian.

A first approach will be the following: we write for a fixed $t$,
$$X_t=\sum_{j=1}^n X_{ t\frac jn} - X_{ t\frac{j-1}n}=:\sum_{j=1}^n Y_{n,j}   $$
and show that the sequence  $\left(\sum\limits_{j=1}^n Y_{n,j}\right)_n$ satisfies Lindeberg's condition for the central limit theorem, i.e., we have to prove that 
$$\tag{Lindeberg} \mbox{ for each  positive }  \varepsilon ,\quad n\mathbb E[X_{t /n}^2 \chi\{| X_{t /n}|\gt \varepsilon\}  ]=0.   $$

> **Claim.** The sequence $(n\mathbb E[|X_{t/n}|^3 ] )_{n\geqslant  n_0}  $ is bounded, where $n_0$ is such that $t/n_0\lt\delta$.

To see this, we use Rosenthal's inequality with the independent and centered family of random variables $(X_{tj/n}-X_{t(j-1)/n} )_{j=1}^n $ and the exponent $3$. We get that 
$$\sum_{j=1}^n\mathbb E|X_{tj/n}-X_{t(j-1)/n} |^3 \leqslant 
K\mathbb E[|X_t|^3 ].$$
The term $\mathbb E[|X_t|^3 ]$ is finite even if $t$ is greater than $\delta$ (we write $X_t$ as a finite sum of increments $X_{t_i}-X_{t_{i-1} } $, and $t_i-t_{i-1}\leqslant\delta$). We thus obtain by stationarity of the increments that 
$$n\mathbb E|X_{t/n}|^3\leqslant KC(t), $$
where $C(t)$ depends only on $t$. This proves the claim.

> **Lemma.** Condition (Lindeberg) is satisfied if for each positive $\varepsilon$, $n\mathbb P(|X_{t/n}|\gt\varepsilon    )\to 0$.

Indeed, we have for each $n$ and $R$,
$$n\mathbb E[X_{t /n}^2 \chi\{| X_{t /n}|\gt \varepsilon\}  ]\leqslant \frac nR\mathbb E|X_{t/n} |^3 +R^2n\mathbb P(|X_{t/n} |\gt\varepsilon )$$
and by the claim, 
$$n\mathbb E\left[X_{t /n}^2 \chi\{| X_{t /n}|\gt \varepsilon\}\right]\leqslant
\frac{ KC(t)}R +R^2n\mathbb P(|X_{t/n} |\gt\varepsilon ).$$
To conclude the proof, we notice that
$$1-\left(1-P(|X_{t/n}|>\varepsilon)\right)^n=P\left(|Y_{n,i}|>\varepsilon\text{ for some }1\le i\le n\right)\to 0$$
as $n\to\infty$ by the uniform continuity of $s\mapsto X_s$ on $[0,t]$. Thus
$n\log\left(1-P(|X_{t/n}|>\varepsilon)\right)\to 0$, but
$$n\log\left(1-P(|X_{t/n}|>\varepsilon)\right)\le -nP(|X_{t/n}|>\varepsilon)\le 0,$$
so we finally get $nP(|X_{t/n}|>\varepsilon)\to 0$, which completes the proof.

Comment: Thank you! Where can I find a proof of Rosenthal's inequality?

Comment: You can find it in Rosenthal's original paper (1971, Israel Journal of Mathematics). There is a proof p.152 in the book _Probability: A Graduate Course_ by Allan Gut.

Answer (score 2):

I just found another proof (not mine) which **does not use** the last hypothesis on the third moments, so I'm writing it here for its own interest.

We use two simple facts:

1. For any $t>0$ the characteristic function of $X_t$ never vanishes: $\mathbb{E}[e^{iuX_t}]\neq 0$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/416412/showing-varphit-neq-0-when-varphi-is-a-characteristic-function-of-an-inf)).
   So there is a well-defined choice of a logarithm, $u\mapsto \ln\mathbb{E}[e^{iuX_t}]$, such that this map is continuous (as $u\in\mathbb{R}$ varies) and null at $u=0$.
   We will implicitly refer to this choice.
2. Fix a time $T>0$. As Davide already showed at the end of his answer, for any $\epsilon$ we have $n\mathbb{P}(|X_{T/n}|>\epsilon)\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.

From the first fact, since $\ln \mathbb{E}[e^{iuX_T}]=\ln \mathbb{E}[e^{iuX_{T/n}}]^n=n\ln\mathbb{E}[e^{iuX_{T/n}}]$,
we have $\ln\mathbb{E}[e^{iX_{T/n}}]=\frac{1}{n}\ln\mathbb{E}[e^{iX_T}]$, so that
$$\mathbb{E}[e^{iX_{T/n}}]=\exp(\frac{1}{n}\ln\mathbb{E}[e^{iX_T}])=1+\frac{1}{n}\ln\mathbb{E}[e^{iX_T}]+O(\frac{1}{n^2})$$
and finally
$$n\mathbb{E}[e^{iX_{T/n}}-1]\to\ln\mathbb{E}[e^{iX_T}]\ \ \ \ (*)$$

Now the second fact implies that

> For any bounded function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=o(x^2)$ we have $n\mathbb{E}[f(X_{T/n})]\to 0$

To prove this put $M:=\|f\|_\infty$ and fix any $\epsilon'>0$. Then we can find some $\epsilon>0$ s.t. for any $|x|\le\epsilon$ we have $|f(x)|\le\epsilon'x^2$,
thus $n|\mathbb{E}[f(X_{T/n})]|\le n|\mathbb{E}[f(X_{T/n})1_{|X_{T/n}|>\epsilon}]|+n|\mathbb{E}[f(X_{T/n})1_{|X_{T/n}|\le\epsilon}]|$.
But the first term tends to $0$ (as it is $\le nM\mathbb{P}(|X_{T/n}|>\epsilon)$), while the second term is $\le n\epsilon'\mathbb{E}[X_{T/n}^2]=\epsilon'T$.
Since $\epsilon'$ is arbitrarily small, this proves our claim.

In particular, choosing $f(x):=\cos (x)-1+\frac{x^2}{2}1_{|x|\le 1}$ and taking the real part of $(*)$, we deduce that the limit
$\lim_{n\to\infty}n\mathbb{E}[X_{T/n}^2 1_{|X_{T/n}|\le 1}]=:A$ exists (and is finite).
In the same way (using the imaginary part of $(*)$) $\lim_{n\to\infty}n\mathbb{E}[X_{T/n} 1_{|X_{T/n}|\le 1}]=:\gamma$ exists.

Finally, with $f(x):=e^{iux}-e^{iux}1_{|x|\le 1}$, we get
$$ g(u):=\ln\mathbb{E}[e^{iuX_T}]=n\ln\mathbb{E}[e^{iuX_{T/n}}]=n\ln\left(\mathbb{E}[e^{iuX_{T/n}}1_{|X_{T/n}|\le 1}]+o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right) $$
and with $f(x):=e^{iux}1_{|x|\le 1}-(1+iux-\frac{u^2}{2}x^2)1_{|x|\le 1}$ (now $u\in\mathbb{R}$ is fixed) we obtain
$$ g(u)=n\ln\left(\mathbb{E}[(1+iuX_{T/n}-\frac{u^2}{2}X_{T/n}^2)1_{|X_{T/n}|\le 1}]+o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)=n\ln\left(1+\frac{iu\gamma}{n}-\frac{u^2}{2n}A+o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)=n\left(\frac{iu\gamma}{n}-\frac{u^2}{2n}A+o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)\to iu\gamma-\frac{u^2}{2}A $$
and this proves that $X_T$ has gaussian density.

(I found this proof sketched in some lecture notes by Peter Tankov.)